# How to calculate 2-norm of a matrix efficiently?

Tags: matlab, matrix, svd, norm

Suppose I have a matrix A. I want to calculate its 2-norm/spectral norm. How can I calculate this efficiently?

I know 2-norm of a matrix is equal to its largest singular value. So, result of the following MATLAB code will be zero

```
>> [u,s,v]=svd(A,'econ');
norm(A,2)-s(1,1)
```

But to know 2-norm I have to calculate SVD of full matrix A, is there any efficient way to calculate 2-norm? Answer in form of MATLAB code will be much appereciated.

Comment: `s(0,0)` is invalid MATLAB syntax. Did you even run this code?

Comment: What's the problem with `norm(A,2)` ? In general, if Matlab has a built-in function it's about the fastest you can get, especially for matrix algebra

Comment: I did, but for large matrices it is no good

Comment: Takes a lot of time

Comment: I bet it will be hard to beat `norm` in terms of precision or speed

Comment: Approximation method will do, @LuisMendo , Do you know any?

Comment: No, sorry. But I see you got a very good answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This example with `norm` and random data

```
A = randn(2000,2000);
tic; 
n1 = norm(A) 
toc;
```

gives

```
n1 =  89.298
Elapsed time is 2.16777 seconds.
```

You can try [`eigs`](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eigs.html) to find only one (the largest) eigenvalue of the symmetric matrix `A'*A` (or `A*A'` if it **is smaller for `A` rectangular**). It uses a [Lanczos iteration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lanczos_algorithm) method.

```
tic; 
B = A'*A; % symmetric positive-definite. B = A*A' if it is smaller
n2 = sqrt(eigs(B, 1)), 
toc
```

it outputs:

```
n2 =  89.298
Elapsed time is 0.311942 seconds.
```

If you don't want to use `norm` or `eigs`, and your matrix `A` has good properties (singular values properly separated), you can try to approximate it with a [power iteration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_iteration) method:

```
tic; 
B = A'*A; % or B = A*A' if it is smaller
x = B(:,1); % example of starting point, x will have the largest eigenvector
x = x/norm(x); 
for i = 1:200 
   y = B*x; 
   y = y/norm(y);
   % norm(x - y); % <- residual, you can try to use it to stop iteration
   x = y; 
end; 
n3 = sqrt(mean(B*x./x)) % translate eigenvalue of B to singular value of A
toc
```

which for the same random matrix (not particularly good properties) gives a `~0.1%` accurate solution:

```
n3 =  89.420
Elapsed time is 0.428032 seconds.
```

Comment: A'*A; this is not possible as my matrix dimension is 100 by 4m
so creating the covariance matrix exceed memory limits
What can I do in this situation?

Comment: even better: `B = A*A'` then

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer!
I have another question if you dont mind
what if both dimensions are large, say 4m by 4m?

Comment: 'm' like in 'millions'?. Well, I guess you handle those matrices as sparse ones. Both eigs and power iteration should be able to handle sparse matrices.